# Can I have a dataframe containing mixed values

Tags: r

How can i get a data frame containing mixture of values. I may like to have something like this

```
 a  b  c  d  e
1 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e
2 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e
3 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e
4 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e
5 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `outer` to achieve your required data frame

```
df <- data.frame(outer(1:5,letters[1:5], FUN = "paste", sep = ""))
setNames(df,letters[1:5])
```

df:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
1 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e
2 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e
3 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e
4 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e
5 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e
```

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
    df<-as.data.frame(outer(1:5,letters[1:5],paste0))

df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e
2 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e
3 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e
4 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e
5 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e
```

The `outer` function applies the third argument to the first two (like a product of arrays, see `?outer`). Here, `paste0` is a shortcut for `paste(..., sep='')` and `letters` is included in `base R`. Use `LETTERS` if you want uppercases.